# why i getting IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

Complete the solution so that it splits the string into pairs of two characters. If the string contains an odd number of characters then it should replace the missing second character of the final pair with an underscore ('_').

Examples:

- 'abc' =>  ['ab', 'c_']
- 'abcdef' => ['ab', 'cd', 'ef']

https://prnt.sc/E2sdtceLtkmF

```
# **My Code:**
```

````
def solution(s):
    ```n = 2
    ```sp = [s[index : index + n] for index in range(0, len(s), n)]
    
    ```if len(sp[-1]) == 1:
        sp[-1] = sp[-1] + "_"
        ```return sp
    ```else:
        ```return sp
````

## **and i geting this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/default/tests.py", line 13, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(solution(inp), exp)
  File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 5, in solution
    if len(sp[-1]) == 1:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**# pls someone help**

Comment: If "len(s) == 0" then "sp" is an empty list from which you can't retrieve the last item.

Comment: your code works fine for me, could you tell us which use case return the error?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/E2sdtceLtkmF

Comment: This error will occur if the string passed to *solution()* is empty

Comment: As @MichaelButscher said, you should add the condition to handle when an empty string comes.

Comment: @GiorgiMaisuradze The first 2 test cases passed. The third test failed

Comment: thanks guys its fixed i add another if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test for the possibility that the input parameter is an empty string.

```
def solution(s):
    n = 2
    sp = [s[index : index + n] for index in range(0, len(s), n)]
    if sp and len(sp[-1]) == 1:
        sp[-1] += '_'
    return sp
```

Answer (score 0):

its fixed by adding another if condition which checking sp is empty or not

```
def solution(s):
    n = 2
    sp = [s[index : index + n] for index in range(0, len(s), n)]

    if len(sp) == 0:
       return sp

    if len(sp[-1]) == 1:
       sp[-1] = sp[-1] + "_"
       return sp

    else:
       return sp
```